# How can I center elements with angular material2?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use https://material.angular.io/ for my new angular 2 cli project and its responsive and web design and ux. 
I am trying to do a footer with it, how can I center the span?

```
<md-toolbar color="secondary">
  <md-toolbar-row>
    <span></span>
  </md-toolbar-row>
</md-toolbar>
```

I am coming from a bootstrap background so I suppose there should be something like  **span  class="md-center"**

Can anyone help me with that? I can't find so much in the docs

Thanks

Comment: You can use [flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) module. Or just add your own css class.

Comment: It seems a very good option to positioning every thing. Thx

Comment: Can't tell if you're sarcastic or not. However, as Sasxa pointed it out, flex-layout is a great solution and gives you far more flexible controls on your display than bootstrap-handlers do.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately), material2 doesn't add those sorts of helper classes. But, it's pretty straight-forward to add such logic yourself with basic css.

To align the text in the center of an element,  use `text-align: center`. This works without issue with a div or anything else with a specified width. In the case of a span, you may want to set the width of the span if you want your content centered across your entire containing element (eg width: 100% or something on the span).

**PS. ng2-material is deprecated**. That project was created when @angular/material was in its infancy to help provide more components than what was available in the official material project at the time. Since the @angular/material project has ramped up, updates on ng2-material have stopped to focus on the official project.

So you may want to investigate making that switch yourself in the long term.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong with what I was using...it is https://github.com/angular/material2. Many thanks your answer is very useful